# Finding xpath for an element loaded by Ajax-json response using class and text

Tags: ajax, json, text, xpath, classname

I have an element like

```
<td class="google-visualization-table-th gradient google-visualization-table-sorthdr">
Project Name
<span class="google-visualization-table-sortind">▼</span>
</td>
```

I tried

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'google-visualization-table-th') and normalize-space(text()) = 'Project Name']")
```

But its not working. Basically its code for Column header and I need to recognize each column header and  print if the heading exist or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: @Mathias it is not catching the element required. Gives "Element not found error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved now, element was not getting identified because they were getting loaded in an iframe. I used the below code o switch to iframe and then did usual operations to track the elements.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 200);
By by = By.id("iframe id");
try {
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(by));
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know which version of XPath you are using, but depending on the exact version, `text()` means different things.

I suspect that the text content of `span`(the weird character ▼) is also part of `td/text()`. This is because `text()` does *not* mean:

> Return the rext nodes of the context node

In this case it means:

> Return the text nodes of the context node and the text nodes of all its decendants.

Use `contains()` also in the second half of the predicate:

```
//td[contains(@class, 'google-visualization-table-th') and contains(.,'Project Name')]
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working, Still giving same error. One thing want to add is content of the page is being generated by AJAX-JSON response which takes a good 3 minutes to load for which I have added a      MySuite.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);